# How can we append an ui.draggable to a target retaining the entire draggable element in its place?

Tags: jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Please see the snippet below. Thank you.

We want to retain the original draggable element to its place.
So that we can use it to other droppable element.

```js
$('.draggable').draggable({
  helper: 'clone'
});

$('.droppable').droppable({
  accept: '.draggable',
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    $(this).append(ui.draggable);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="droppable" id="drop-one"></div>
<div class="droppable" id="drop-two"></div>
<div class="droppable"id="drop-three"></div>

<div id="draggables">
  <div class="draggable"></div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You where close to the answer but made a mistake in the **drop function**.

You writed:

```
$(this).append(ui.draggable);
```

But you have to use the clone function.

```
$(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this);
```

**Code Snippet** (i added colors to see whats happening)

```js
    $(".draggable").draggable({cursor: "crosshair", revert: "invalid", helper: "clone", start: function(event, ui) {} });

    $('.droppable').droppable({
        accept: '.draggable',
        drop: function(e, ui) {
            //$(this).append(ui.draggable);
            $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="draggables" style="padding-bottom: 25px;">
  <div class="draggable" style="width: 100px; height: 25px; text-align: center; background-color: red; color: aliceblue;">DRAG ME</div>
</div>


    <div class="droppable" id="drop-one" style="float:left; background-color: antiquewhite; width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
    <div class="droppable" id="drop-two" style="overflow: hidden; background-color: aquamarine; width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Crezzur. I was moving the entire draggable element all this time.